# Managing the life cycle of auth tokens, local storage, httponly cookies, etc

Tags: authentication, cookies, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

As I have been learning web development I have ran into many situations where the *why* is less clear than the *how*. In the case of authentication tokens I have found inadequate answers to the question of why tokens may exist either as elements of an HTTP request/response body, or strictly in headers (as cookies).

I developed what I thought was a reasonable understanding of how cookie-based authentication might work where most/all of the work was *implied* by cookie passing between client browser and the backend:

```
1) Authenticate with backend
2) Backend replies with Set-Cookie headers containing auth (and perhaps refresh) tokens
3) Subsequent queries will (can) contain all site cookies, and so auth can be verified in backend
```

But in general I found that it doesn't quite (always?) work this way. For instance, `djangorestframework-simplejwt` expects, by default, that the `Authorization: Bearer <auth token>` be present in the requests.

**- Why put the same information *already present in cookies* inside additional headers?**

I found a well detailed example flow for differing starting scenarios (previously logged in, new tab, new user, etc) [here](https://briancaffey.github.io/jp/2021/08/07/authenticating-requests-with-jwt-tokens-stored-in-httponly-cookies-in-django/).

---

**- What is the de-facto "modern" way to manage auth cookies?**

Using the same django package mentioned above, it nearly seems like it expects something like this:

```
1) authenticate with backend
2) backend sends auth/refresh tokens to client
3) client caches tokens in local storage?
4) subsequent request to the website contain tokens retrieved from local storage
```

Regarding (2) above, this package will, in fact, provide `auth` and `refresh` tokens in cookies *AND* in the body of the response. Presumably so clients can cache their values persistently somewhere (local storage?). By default, cookie tokens are sent as HttpOnly.

**- What's the point of sending it in the body *and* in the headers (as a cookie)?**

There are an infinite number of ways I can *make it work* by gathering all the bits of knowledge I've come across. But making it work *securely* without introducing dramatic failures, especially given that I'm a new convert from embedded development, makes it all the more concerning.

I feel as if there is a lot of *implied knowledge* in all of this. Frameworks show you how to use them, but, again, not the *why* of their architecture designs. Does everyone just know this stuff by now or do frameworks typically handle all the magic and most developer aren't concerned with the details so long as it works?